# Initialize Mocks in test before @BeforeStep

Tags: java, mockito, spring-batch, spring-boot-test

I have a custom reader with an @BeforeStep function in order to initialize some data. These data are comming from an external database.

```java
@Component
public class CustomReader implements ItemReader<SomeDTO> {

    private RestApiService restApiService;

    private SomeDTO someDTO;

    @BeforeStep
    private void initialize() {
        someDTO = restApiService.getData();
    }

    @Override
    public SomeDTO read() {
        ...    
        return someDTO
    }

}
```

In my unit test i need to mock the calls to the external database.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = NedBatchApplication.class)
public class CustomReaderTest {

    @Autowired
    CustomReader customReader;

    @Mock
    RestApiService restApiService;

    @Before
    private void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(customReader, "restApiService", restApiService);
        Mockito.when(restApiService.getData().thenReturn(expectedData);
    }
}
```

The problem i am facing is the @BeforeStep is executed before the @Before from the unit test, when i lauch my Test. So restApiService.getData() returns null instead of expectedData.

Is there a way to achieve what i want or do i need to do it with a different approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some reflexion with a co-worker he gave me a solution :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = NedBatchApplication.class)
public class CustomReaderTest {

  CustomReader customReader;

  @Mock
  RestApiService restApiService;

  @Before
  private void setup() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      Mockito.when(restApiService.getData().thenReturn(expectedData);

      this.customReader = new CustomReader(restApiService);
  }

 @Test
 public void test() {
   customReader.initialize();
   (...)
 }
}
```

Comment: this shit not working pls check before post

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the `BeforeStep` is running before the `Before` annotation (by using logging or similar?).

It's possible your Mockito invocation is not fully correct. Try using `Mockito.doReturn(expectedData).when(restApiService).getData()` instead.

As an alternative approach, if the `RestApiService` was autowired in your custom reader, you'd be able to use the `@InjectMocks` annotation on the custom reader declaration in your test, which would cause the mocked version of your `restApiService` to be injected to the class during the test.

Comment: Yes i am certain that `BeforeStep` is running before the `Before` annotation by using  BreakPoints in debug mode.

Comment: So it's most likely that using the `@Autowired` annotation causes your CustomReader to be fully initialised before the `BeforeStep` of your test is run. Have you tried changing your code so that the `RestAPIService` is autowired, allowing you to mock it using the `@InjectMocks` and `@MockBean` annotations in your tests?

Comment: I will give it a try and keep you updated on the result. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: I have tried a different approach. i made initialize() public and in the @Before annotated method i have created a new CustomReader like this customReader = new CustomReader(restApiService). Then in my test method i do customReader.initialize() and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when using Spring based tests, try to make dependencies like `restApiService` (the ones you would like to mock) to be spring beans, and then you can instruct spring to create mock and inject into application context during the application context creation with the help of `@MockBean` annotation:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;  
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = NedBatchApplication.class)
public class CustomReaderTest {

    @MockBean
    private RestApiService restApiService; 
}
```

Comment: restApiService is annotated with @Service.

Changing the the @Mock in @MockBean doesn't change the result.

The problem is that the `BeforeStep`is executed before the `Before` annotation and witch makes  `restApiService.getData()`return null, and my reader return null as well in the `read()`method.